# Minimizing numerically a nondifferentiable function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-regression, likelihood

Many (likelihood) functions are not differentiable at the optimal point. Does this cause problems
a) in the numerical methods used to minimize the function based on the gradient?
b) in the statistical inference based in the Hessian matrix of $f$?

In my applied case, the absolute value appears in the likelihood function due to the use of the change of variable formula. 
With R, and the nlm and optimx packages, it turns out that at the candidate point for a "minimum"

1. the gradient is not equal to zero
2. the Hessian matrix is not positive definite

Can the point found by "nlm" or "omptimx" be considered as a minimum despite the gradient being nonzero?
What shall be done regarding the estimation of the variance matrix?
Do you know references in this problem?

Here is a very simplified one dimensional example of what (I think) happens in my likelihood minimization. Well in this one-dimensional case the Hessian is always found to be positive definite, but whether it can be used for computing the variance matrix is still not obvious to me.

```r
f = function(x) abs(x^3 - 3*x)  
curve(abs(x^3 - 3*x), -3, 3, col = "violet")  
mle = nlm(f,3,iterlim=1000, hessian=TRUE)  
mle
```

Comment: I am curious: could you exhibit a likelihood function (using plausible data) that is not differentiable at its optimum *and* where that optimum occurs within the interior of the parameter space?  If not, then perhaps the thing to be concerned about is what to replace the Hessian (and Fisher Information) by when optima occur on the boundary.

Comment: Actually, I now think that the problem of finding a Hessian which is not positive definite at the minimum has nothing to do with the non-differentiability issue.   I looked the loglikelihood it looks very smooth at the optimum… but the code is a bit too long to be posted here.